# Dragging a textarea

Tags: java, swing, draggable, jtextarea

**Code in Question:**

```
    textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            posX = e.getX();
            posY = e.getY();
        }
    });
    textArea.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() - posX, e.getYOnScreen() - posY);
        }
    });
```

**Background:**

I have a JFrame, in that JFrame there is a JScrollPane, and in the JScrollPane there is a JTextArea called "textArea". This JTextArea take up the entire JFrame and the JFrame is undecorated. So to give some perspective, here is generally what the JFrame looks like...

[image: example image]

When the mouse clicks within the JTextArea and moves, the entire window is dragged. Everything is setup to not be focus able for this work, it's meant to be an overlay.

**Issue:**

The code listed above works fine and the world is at peace. But once there is enough text for the vertical scroll bar to appear (There is no horizontal because of line wrapping), dragging the window becomes an issue. When you click and just begin to move, the JFrame instantly moves much higher on the screen. The lines in JTextArea, the higher it moves up when you try to move it. I assume that the get*OnScreen() methods are issue because it's all relevant to the JTextArea.

**Class in Question:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane textAreaScroll;
    private int posX = 0;
    private int posY = 0;

public Main() {
    initComponents();
    initListeners();
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        addLine(i+" Hello");            
    }
}

public void addLine(String line){
    textArea.append("\n> "+line);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}

private void initListeners(){
    textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            posX = e.getX();
            posY = e.getY();
        }
    });
    textArea.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() - posX, e.getYOnScreen() - posY);
        }
    });
}

private void initComponents() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {}

    textAreaScroll = new JScrollPane();
    textArea = new JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setBackground(new Color(130,210,255,130));
    setFocusCycleRoot(false);
    setFocusable(false);
    setFocusableWindowState(false);
    setName("main");
    setOpacity(0.4f);
    setResizable(false);

    textAreaScroll.setBorder(null);
    textAreaScroll.setFocusable(false);
    textAreaScroll.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 0, 14));
    textArea.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    textArea.setText("> Hello world!\n> another line!");
    textArea.setBorder(null);
    textArea.setFocusable(false);
    textArea.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    textAreaScroll.setViewportView(textArea);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(textAreaScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(textAreaScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 214, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: post your code in executable format.

Comment: Added code in an executable format.

Comment: Added "for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){addLine(i+" Hello");}"

When you start the program, it should be in the bugged state, remove the for loop to have it in the working state.

Comment: To anyone looking at this, another solution that I found was to create a layered pane, create the textarea, then overlay a panel over the textarea and make the panel non opaque. I adjusted the panel to not include the scroll bar afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your diagnosis was absolutely spot on:

> When you click and just begin to move, the JFrame instantly moves
>   much higher on the screen. The lines in JTextArea, the higher it moves
>   up when you try to move it. I assume that the get*OnScreen() methods
>   are issue because it's all relevant to the JTextArea.

So to resolve this use [*GlassPane*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) of `JFrame` to attach `MouseXXXListener`s thus we can get correct co-ordinates when dragging, the main problem with this solution is *glasspane* will consume events that are meant for other components on `JFrame`, this can be overcome by redispatching the `MouseEvent`s appropriately):

- Create `JPanel` (this *glassPane*/`JPanel` will be transparent via `setOpaque(false)`), attach `xxxAdapters` here.
- Create custom listener class to redispacth `MouseEvent`s to the necessary components (as *glasspane* will consume all events to the `JTextArea`/`JScollPane`)
- Set `JPanel` as GlassPane of  your `JFrame` via `JFrame#setGlassPane(..)` .
- set `JFrame` visible than set *glassPane* visible via `setVisible(true)` (this has been a Swing glitch for some time if you set it visible before the frame is visible it wont be shown).

Here is your fixed code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane textAreaScroll;
    private JPanel glassPane;//create variable for glasspane

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
        initListeners();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            addLine(i + " Hello");
        }
    }

    public void addLine(String line) {
        textArea.append("\n> " + line);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        GlassPaneListener gpl = new GlassPaneListener(textAreaScroll.getVerticalScrollBar(), this);
        //add the adapters/listeners to the glasspane
        glassPane.addMouseMotionListener(gpl);
        glassPane.addMouseListener(gpl);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        }

        textAreaScroll = new JScrollPane();
        textArea = new JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setBackground(new Color(130, 210, 255, 130));
        setFocusCycleRoot(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setFocusableWindowState(false);
        setName("main");
        setOpacity(0.4f);
        setResizable(false);

        textAreaScroll.setBorder(null);
        textAreaScroll.setFocusable(false);
        textAreaScroll.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 0, 14));
        textArea.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setRows(5);
        textArea.setText("> Hello world!\n> another line!");
        textArea.setBorder(null);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        textAreaScroll.setViewportView(textArea);
        textAreaScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(textAreaScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(textAreaScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 214, Short.MAX_VALUE));

        //create and make glasspane not opaque
        glassPane = new JPanel();
        glassPane.setOpaque(false);

        //set glasspane as JFrame glassPane
        setGlassPane(glassPane);

        pack();

        setVisible(true);//set JFrame visible

        //glassPane can only be setVisible after JFrame is visible
        glassPane.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GlassPaneListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

    private int posX = 0;
    private int posY = 0;
    Toolkit toolkit;
    private final Container contentPane;
    private final Component textAreaScroll;
    private final Component glassPane;
    private final JFrame frame;
    private boolean wasClickOnInterestedComponent = false;

    public GlassPaneListener(Component textAreaScroll, JFrame frame) {
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        this.textAreaScroll = textAreaScroll;
        this.frame = frame;
        this.glassPane = frame.getGlassPane();
        this.contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!redispatchMouseEvent(e)) {
            frame.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() - posX, e.getYOnScreen() - posY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!redispatchMouseEvent(e)) {//check if event was redispatched if not its meant for us :)
            posX = e.getX();
            posY = e.getY();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        wasClickOnInterestedComponent = false;
    }

    private boolean redispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        Point glassPanePoint = e.getPoint();
        Container container = contentPane;
        Point containerPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane, glassPanePoint, contentPane);

        // The mouse event is probably over the content pane.
        // Find out exactly which component it's over.
        Component component = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(container, containerPoint.x,
                containerPoint.y);

        if ((component != null) && (component.equals(textAreaScroll)) || wasClickOnInterestedComponent) {
            wasClickOnInterestedComponent = true;//so that if we drag iur cursor off JScrollBar tghe window wont be moved
            // Forward events over the scrollbar
            Point componentPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane, glassPanePoint, component);
            component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component, e.getID(), e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers(),
                    componentPoint.x, componentPoint.y, e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger()));
            return true;//the event was redispatched
        } else {
            return false;//event was not redispatched
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer in such a helpful way! My next question would have been re-dispatching the mouse events but you anticipated that. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Joe its a pleasure glad to be of help

Comment: Minor issue that I fixed with your code, when you click on the scroll bar and move the mouse outside of the bounds of the JFrame, a 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source' exception is thrown on this line 'componentPoint.x, componentPoint.y, e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger()));'.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying *JFrame instantly moves much higher on the screen. The lines in JTextArea* but actually it is scrolled down so only last few lines are visible.

If you would like to see textArea content from top, change is here

```
initComponents();
initListeners();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   addLine(i + " Hello");
}
//set scrolling position to top
textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Comment: I apologize for not being completely clear, the "moves much higher" is kinda vague looking back at it. When I said that, I was referencing the entire JFrame was being moved up in relation to the entire screen. Like when you would grab a window and drag it to a new section of the screen, except in my case, when you begin the drag, the window instantly offsets it self higher on the screen. 

None the less, thank you for your tip :).